# How do I rotate an object with a image on it?

Tags: animation

It’s hard to word it but I have a 3D model of a shirt and I have a png on the back of it. But when I go onto that animation tab, and try to rotate it the image i have on the object(the shirt) it doesn’t stay at the same spot.[image]

Comment: what method do you use to put the image on the object? Please show your Shader Editor

Comment: I did it exactly how I did this guy did it. https://youtu.be/htV_BhUZwcI don’t know the ñame of how thats method is called but I’ll add the picture

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand your image is actually not part of the T-shirt material, it is an image plane that is shrinkwrapped around your T-shirt. So if you want to keep this solution, you need this plane to follow the T-shirt object. To do so, the simplest way is to parent the image to the T-shirt. If it doesn't give you satisfaction you should consider using the image as an *Image Texture* within the T-shirt material.

Comment: Oh okay, I’ll try out and let you know if I have issues